# What should I do to make termcolor work in pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

why termcolor coes not work in pycharm? i install it from cmd but it work in vscod[image]

you can see  my code

```
def print_board():
    j = 1
    for i in board:
        end = " "
        if j % 3 == 0:
            end = "\n\n"
        if i == 'X':
            print(colored(f"[{i}]", "red"), end=end)
        elif i == 'O':
            print(colored(f"[{i}]", 'blue'), end=end)
        else:
            print(f"[{i}]", end=end)
        j += 1
```

Comment: Have you tried turning on "Emulate terminal in output console" in the Run/Debug Configurations menu?

Comment: Thank you very much, it was fixed after I ticked the emulate terminal option.Can you explain the reason why other libraries like colorma worked but termcolor was not active?

Comment: According the the colorama docs, they specifically strip out ansi escape sequences used on other platforms and convert them to sys calls. I assume this could be a place where the 2 libraries differ, and so emulating a proper console would allow termcolor to work in its intended environment

Comment: yes thank you...i solved it

Answer (score 0):

try this code in print:

```
print(colored(f"[{i}]", 'blue','on_white',['blink'],force_color='True'), end=end)
```